# What is ::after inside all my elements in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I seen `::after` text as child in all my HTML elements in chrome console. What are those ? why they appear in my website ?

I used bootstrap, Jquery, Javascript in my application

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%3A%3Aafter (leads to either https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after or http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp)

Comment: What? How can we possibly offer an answer to this, given that you've given us no means to reproduce the problem? What `::after` *is* is easy, but *why* it is, or they are, there is impossible to say without seeing actual code.

Comment: @DavidThomas the problem with this question isn't that it can't be reproduced, it just shows no effort at all on finding it out for themselves.

Comment: @Joey: I disagree with your first statement, and agree with your second.

Comment: @DavidThomas: If you know something about ::after, you can comment here, otherwise it's optional

Comment: @Joeytje50 Have you tried your own link? The problem here is that Google ignores the `::` and because of that hardly returns useful results, unless you know specificly what you are looking for. I can imaging that if you haven't heard of this phenomenon before that it's hard to find a proper explanation.

Comment: @GolezTrol I have, yes. It's probably that Google somehow uses my IP to modify my search results then, because even in incognito it results in http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp as 2nd link, and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after as 4th link.

Comment: @DavidThomas I can easily recreate the situation. In chrome, right-click -> inspect element on the div in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9EyuE/. You'll see `::after` as child of that div. Easy enough to recreate if you know enough about CSS and Chrome's dev tools.

Answer (score 3):

::after is a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements). They will only show up if you put something in them in your CSS. Chrome displays them because sometimes you need to change them when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

They are a `pseudo elements`, through which you can add additional content to your elements.

For instance, you can use this CSS to add quotes around paragraphs with the class 'quoted'.

```
p.quoted::before {
  content: "'";
}
p.quoted::after {
  content: "'";
}
```

Apart from content, you can apply additional styles to these pseudo elements as well, so you can make elaborate layouts with little or no extra markup.

For lots of inspiration, see: http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/